# Validate field null ou not null, Error: Invalid Chai property: toBe. Did you mean "to"?

Tags: postman, chai

I'm trying to validate the field (IdCons) if it is null or not, but I'm always getting the same error, I will be grateful if someone helps me.

**this is the return of Json that I want to validate**

```
  {
    "idP": "86b685aa-bdae-4ee7-acdb-420adf22e2b4",
    "idCons": "e1e09da5-4de6-4ea1-bdc6-725119939b1a",
    "dataConsulta": "2020-05-18T21:27:42.597Z",
    "dataValidade": "2020-06-17T21:27:42.597Z",
    "parametros": {
        "RET_RESPOSTA": "VER",
        "RET_LIMITE": "0"                   
    }}
```

**my script for validation**

```
pm.test("Resultado deve retornar SUCESSO se o Driver de Passagem possuir Parametros", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var DriverD = parseFloat(jsonData.idCons);
pm.expect(DriverD).not.toBe(null);});  

pm.test("Resultado deve retornar SUCESSO 200 OK", function () {
pm.response.to.have.status(200);});
```

Answer (score 0):

`chai` does not have the `toBe()` method. You should use:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('61915245', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const jsonData = {
      idP: '86b685aa-bdae-4ee7-acdb-420adf22e2b4',
      idCons: 'e1e09da5-4de6-4ea1-bdc6-725119939b1a',
      dataConsulta: '2020-05-18T21:27:42.597Z',
      dataValidade: '2020-06-17T21:27:42.597Z',
      parametros: {
        RET_RESPOSTA: 'VER',
        RET_LIMITE: '0',
      },
    };
    const DriverD = parseFloat(jsonData.idCons);
    expect(DriverD).not.to.be.null;
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  61915245
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (18ms)
```